Does India import components for its missile program, or are they 100% domestic?
Tell me if I am wrong, but I never saw such news as the USA putting sanctions on component-sellers of Indian missile programs while putting sanctions on entities selling missile components to Pakistan,  is commonplace.
Does India import components for its missile program and the USA ignores them, or is their production 100% domestic?

Maybe I'm missing something, but why should Pakistan and India be treated the same by the US?

@user366312 then why is it part of the premise/exposition of your question?

Would there be a reason for this other than the USA being more allied with India than with Pakistan? They also probably have fewer problems with France or Israel getting missile components than Iran or North Korea.

You haven't done your research. India's space, missile and nuclear programs have faced sanctions many times.
In his autobiography Wings of Fire, Dr. Abdul Kalam (who once headed India's missile development program) provides many examples of how the west tried to sabotage India's space, nuclear and missile development programs by either restricting technologies or by sanctions.

Prithvi was launched at 11:23 hrs on 25 February 1988. It was an epoch-making event in the history of rocketry in the country ... The launch of Prithvi sent shock waves across the unfriendly neighbouring countries. The response of the Western bloc was initially one of shock and then of anger. A seven-nation technology embargo was clamped, making it impossible for India to buy anything even remotely connected with the development of guided missiles. The emergence of India as a self-reliant country in the field of guided missiles upset all the developed nations of the world.

(As the Missile Technology Control Regime emerged, India created a list of technologies that it anticipated would be denied to it and started work on indigenizing it. In his book The Path Unexplored, Sivathanu Pillai, who headed the BrahMos missile venture, writes the MTCR was in some ways a blessing in disguise for India as it enabled it to achieve technological independence, which he describes as a “mini freedom struggle” for India. By the time Dr. Abdul Kalam retired as DRDO chief, DRDO had achieved more than 50% indigenization in 15 years.)
While India has been successful in indigenizing many defence technologies, neither its space, nuclear or missile programs are "100% domestic". Due to the limited budget (compared to the developed nations) that India can spend on defence R&D, it has a policy of not "reinventing the wheel" and focused on indigenization of technology only when it is denied access to it or when it determines that it cannot depend on a foreign supplier for some necessary technology.
(Sometime, this lesson is learnt the hard way. For example, during the Kargil war with Pakistan, India requested access to US military GPS for precision bombing but the US denied this request as Pakistan is a US ally. So India decided to create its own satellite navigation system for its military:

Initially, the U.S. Air Force and Department of Defense (DoD) used a technology called “selective availability,” which introduced intentional error into nonmilitary GPS receivers, to retain the best accuracy for military use. The United States used selective availability to degrade GPS accuracy to Indian military forces during the 1999 Kargil War, which hindered Indian operations. This incident highlighted the advantages afforded to forces using GPS, as well as the disadvantages to those without. The U.S. action led India, and others, to develop their own systems.

Source: Regaining the GPS Strategic Advantage).
There have also been a few incidents of India receiving compromised components from foreign suppliers.
That said, due to improved relations with the west, today India has much easier access to western technologies than in the past.

The United States on Monday designated India as a Strategic Trade Authorization-1 (STA-1) country - a status that will allow the country to buy highly advanced and sensitive technologies from America. With such coveted designation, India will now be at par with the United States' closest allies and partners such as NATO ... Currently there are 36 countries on STA-1 list. India is the only South Asian country to be on the list. Other Asian countries designated as STA-1 are Japan and South Korea.

Source: India becomes first South Asian country to get access to America's cutting-edge technology.
A major reason for this is because India historically has held steadfast to the idea of non-proliferation of space, nuclear and missile technology, especially those received from foreign powers. Despite not signing the NPT or the MTCR (till recently) India stringently adhered to all its terms. Its defence research and development is also highly partitioned and "firewalled" (even within departments) to ensure that defence technologies sourced from one foreign country does not "leak" to another. India also tries to be transparent when integrating technologies from different foreign suppliers (for example, Americans do not like any Russian tech to be used on their weapon platforms, and vice-versa - so India seeks permission from the original owner before modifying any platform with foreign components).
All this is in sharp contrast to Pakistan's history, which is a known proliferator of both missile and nuclear technology - especially to countries like Iran and North Korea that the US (and many in the west) considers its enemy. (Is it really surprising that a foreign country hesitates to supply weapon technology to a country that may betray it by sharing it with its foreign enemies?)
While access to defence technology from the west has become easier, (compared to Pakistan) India still faces many restrictions on access to high-end "dual-use" technology.

Perhaps you can elaborate on the last para, since that is the actual question.

@264champagnebottlesonice There isn't much to add - the west have only provided access to dual-use technologies that we already have access to from other sources or have indigenously developed (or are developing). And note that access to such technologies doesn't also imply technology transfer.

They probably import at least some parts. E.g. for the Brahmos cruise/anti-ship missile:

Major airframe assemblies such as non-metallic air frame sections comprising ramjet fuel tank and pneumatic fuel supply system which form the integral part of the Ramjet Engine are now locally developed.

Says Wikipedia citing a 2021 article in The Hindu. Which probably means some other parts are/were still imported from Russia.
It's harder [for me] to find similar info about their ballistic missile program. As Iran's import of rocket fuel mixers (from China) was in the news lately, I checked out India's situation, and they seem to have been producing their own mixers for a while. Electronics-wise they are still pretty dependendent on the West apparently, but as we saw from analyses of Russian missiles etc. landed in Ukraine, it's pretty easy to source diverted dual-use components.
India wasn't prevented by trade sanctions from developing a domestic rocket engine for commercial/civilian launchers, in cooperation with Ukraine, and starting from a Soviet design. (Those use liquid fuel, by the way, and are somewhat of a different beast than modern military ones, as they are not intended to be kept fueled for long before launch.)
